# Can QTimer fire when the queue is not empty?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtimer

If there are both overdue QTimer-s and events waiting in event queue, what will QT dispatcher do?  Fire the timers and run functions connected to them, or process events?  In other words, can a timer fire when the event queue is not empty?

Answer (score 1):

A QTimer firing **is** an event. See:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#timerEvent

Timer events are processed together with all the other events. `QTimer` is just a nice API around timer events, so that you don't have to deal with them manually. The QTimer class takes care of that for you.

Comment: What does it mean then: "As a special case, a QTimer with a timeout of 0 will time out as soon as all the events in the window system's event queue have been processed." ?

Comment: @user31264 It just means that the timer event will be processed last, after the window system events are processed.

Comment: Does it mean that it has lower priority than all other events?  Because if it is an event like all events, it should be processed according to its priority and time of posting.

Comment: @user31264 The documentation says that it's processed after the other events, so yes, it does have lower priority. But not sure if that matters much. It's guaranteed to be processed on the next main event loop iteration. Whether that's before or after the other events doesn't really matter.